# Expo project out of sync

Tags: react-navigation, expo

I am working on an Expo project with React Navigation. The code is working properly in my local environment, but my co-worker is seeing an issue where the TabNavigator tabs do not work (almost as if they are frozen).

We are working on the same code base and each cloned the code into a new location and installed all packages fresh. I'm still not seeing the issue and he is. We can't seem to get our code in sync.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Do you have a yarn.lock/package-lock.json file? If you're not committing it to GIT then you should.

Comment: We are not committing it. Will try this and see if it resolves the issue. Thank you!